# Added custom field to projects but can't use PMProjectExt

Tags: acumatica

I'm making a button to create a SOOrder from the Project. I'd like to write the newly created number back to the project, so I've added a custom field for that. It's on the form and the whole process works great.

That said, at the end when I try to write back to the project I get the following error any time I try to reference PMProjectExt:

`error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'PMProjectExt' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Ideally my update line looks like this  `Base.Caches[typeof(PMProject)].SetValue<PMProjectExt.usrTEKSOOrderNbr>(TheRow, header.OrderNbr);`

But even something as simple as declaring a variable (eg  `PMProjectExt testExt;` with the PMProjectExt gets the same error.

I'm sure I'm doing something really stupid, but I can't seem to resolve it.

Comment: It might be best to keep the update to PMProject on the sales order graph. So when you save the sales order it will save the order number also to the project. When you split the update you run the risk of one update persisting and the other update no persisting.  In your case however it sounds like the code cannot find PMProjectExt and the namespace you are using in your customization. What is the full namespace where PMProjectExt exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, turns out that Projects used to be Contracts. So to get the extension on Projects you need to use contracts like this:

```csharp
  PMProject TheRow = (PMProject)e.Row;
  ContractExt TheExt = PXCache<Contract>.GetExtension<CT.ContractExt>(TheRow);
  string refNbr = TheExt.UsrTEKSOOrderNbr;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update a project, I recommend to instantiate the PMProject graph, assign the current record & update the user-field value.  Finally persist the changes to the graph.  Something like this.

```
ProjectEntry graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<ProjectEntry>();
PMProject currentProject = graph.Project.Search<PMProject.contractCD>(Base,[your project nbr])
if (currentProject!=null)
{
  graph.Project.Current = currentProject;
  PMProjectExt projectExtension = PXCache<PMProject>.GetExtension<PMProjectExt>(currentProject);
  projectExtension.usrTEKSOOrderNbr = "ABC123";

  graph.Actions.PressSave();
  graph.Clear();   
}
```

Comment: While that's probably a better solution, I'm still getting  ```error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'PMProjectExt' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) ```

Comment: Where is PMProjectExt declared?  Which namespace?  Can you fully qualify the declaration?